# What do decode surface and output surface mean? How do they impact the decode performance?

Tags: performance, output, decode, nvidia, surface

I am studying NVIDIA decode samples. I noticed that there are 2 parameters named `ulNumDecodeSurfaces` and `ulNumOutputSurfaces`. The max value of `ulNumDecodeSurfaces` is 20, the max value of `ulNumOutputSurfaces` is 8.

Does anyone know what these 2 parameters mean? Will they impact the decode performance? How do they impact the decode performance?

Answer (score 3):

They are found along with comments in cuviddec.h (available online at https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/cuviddec_8h_source.html).

ulNumOutputSurfaces is the maximum number of output surfaces that the decoder can be writing each image to.

ulNumDecodeSurfaces has the comment: "Maximum number of internal decode surfaces", which is somewhat more ambiguous.  The source code for this library is not available outside nVidia, so we'll have to rely on someone from nVidia responding with an authoritative answer.  However, looking at the values that this is set to in the example code makes it look like this is the number of frames in the internal decoding pipeline.  Presumably, making this larger increases GPU memory use but provides additional buffering so that the pipeline is less likely to block because the application is not pulling frames off the decoder fast enough.  There is a comment elsewhere that indicates that there should always be at least 2 frames in the decode queue to keep all of the decode engines busy.